# Android and BarTender Arduino 1.0.5-r2

Tags: android, ios, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

I am creating drink using Android nexux5 and Arduino Board. 
When I send the data from android device to Arduino Board It giving me the output

"Evt disconnected Advertising time out error"

I am sending the data using command

i:Rum~0;c:lime juice~45^;

This is running successfully by iPhone device but when running on android device the Serial monitor giving "Evt disconnected Advertising time out"  .

Please also refer the the output image from the below link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncklciwm70y5azy/Output.png

In the image the upper code is for iPhone and the lower code for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was giving the error "Evt disconnected Advertising time out"  because my android device Bluetooth was not working properly.

I tried the same code with another android devices it working fine.